# make variables available inside function/class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var g = $('#go');
var z = $('#are');
```

I have variables i want to make available inside the y class to alertData and hideData.

What is the easiest way to do this?

```
var y = {    

    alertData: function (){
        alert('z');      
    },
    hideData: function (){
        $(this).hide();
    } 

};
```

Comment: Well z should work if you remove the speechmarks as far as I can tell?

Comment: i want to set them inside y though

Comment: Variables declared in a higher scope are always available in lower scopes, but you're alerting a string, not a variable.

Comment: If you invoke `hideData` using `y.hideData`, the `this` in `$(this).hide()` will be `y`.

Comment: Well just declare them inside of y?

Comment: @galdikas you can't make `var` declarations inside of an _Object_ literal, or have I missed something fundamental in my knowledge of _JavaScript_?

Comment: @PaulS. Sorry, your right. is it something like y.property = "hello"??

Answer (score 3):

You could always do :

```
var y = {    
    g : $('#go'),
    z : $('#are'),
    alertData: function (){
        alert(this.z);      
    },
    hideData: function (){
        this.g.hide();
    } 
};
```

or

```
var y = {    
    alertData: function (elem){
        alert(elem.prop('id'));      
    },
    hideData: function (elem){
        elem.hide();
    } 
};

var g = $('#go');
var z = $('#are');

y.alertData(g);
y.hideData(z);
```

If you're looking for chainable methods, you should be using `$.fn` to create the methods.

Answer (score 0):

either you can make g and z global variable and then they will be available inside any function you want.

OR you can pass in the variables when calling alert data and hide data and this is the preferred approach and now you functions are independent of the global variables and later can be used at other places also

Answer (score 0):

Create two local variables in y and assign them from outside so that they will be part of the object. By doing so, you can use them where-ever you want inside y.

Comment: what is the correct way to create the variables inside the object so they are available to everything inside the object?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.g = $('#go');
window.z = $('#are');

function somefunction(){
   console.log(g);
   console.log(z);
}
```

Comment: You can't `var` an _Object_ property; `window` being said _Object_. `var window.foo = 'bar';` `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Answer (score 0):

Add it like this:

```
var y = {    
    g:"",
    z:"",
    alertData: function (){
        alert(this.z);      
    },
    hideData: function (){
        this.g.hide();
    } 

};
```

and assign the values using `y.g = anything` and `y.z = anything`

Answer (score 0):

Or if they need to be private, here is the module pattern:

```
var y = (function() {
    var g = $('#go');
    var z = $('#are');
    return {
        alertData: function() {
            alert(z);
        }
        hideData: function() {
            z.hide();
        }
    }
}())
```

That will make `g` and `z` visible to all functions in the object returned by the above self-invoking function, while `y.z` (or `y.g`) throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

defining a simple varible become global in javascript, that is why its not satisfied the property of oops i.e encapsulation. So if you run this that will work.:

```
g = $('<p>');
z = $('#are');

function somefunction(){
 console.log(g);
 console.log(z);
}

somefunction()
```

g and z become global variable..